# Как отобразить HTML в TextView? Чтобы переход по ссылкам работал

Tags: android

Как отобразить HTML в TextView? Чтобы переход по ссылкам работал?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TextView i1 = ...;
i1.setText(Html.fromHtml("Моя ссылка <a href=\"...\">здесь</a>"));
```

Comment: Да, и еще нужно добавить    android:autoLink="web"